# Commenting with no reputation

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to allow people with no reputation to comment on posts? We *need* experts to give their opinions, and sometimes that starts with just a comment or two, as we saw unfold recently. It'd be shame to drive off knowledgeable folks just because of some points game.

Comment: I'm all for doing anything to make it easier for people to ease in to using the site, but I have no idea how to accomplish what you're asking about, so I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @JoelDerfner Well, there's a feature request tag, so I hope that a StackExchange moderator can maybe weigh in.

Answer (score 3):

This is a system-wide setting, so it's not likely to change.  Here's a summary of one of the many MSE posts on the subject: [Why does Stack Overflow prevent new users from commenting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114534/300411):

- Stack Exchange is not a forum, but allowing new users to comment encourages them to treat it like one
- Stack Exchange is built on self-moderation, but comments are hard to self-moderate (most comments in the system that are deleted are ultimately deleted by moderators)
- Comments are easier to abuse

That said, there are technical workarounds, as Joonas says; moderators can convert answers into comments.  But unfortunately (in this particular case, anyway), it's highly unlikely that low-rep users will be given the ability to comment freely.

Comment: In that case, seems like they should have given moderator status before making it public beta. That would prevent silly incidents.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Yes, but I think they prefer to evaluate the candidates over a longer period of time: Portuguese, for example, didn't get its moderators until several weeks into public beta.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible once we have our own moderators.
A moderator can turn an answer into a comment.
The procedure is roughly this:

- A new user posts a comment as an answer.
- Others can comment that it would be better as a comment and suggest this.
- If the poster agrees, a custom flag can be raised to explain the situation.
- A moderator can turn the answer into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Joonas proposes, I'd like to pitch the idea of **discouraging** users from downvoting comments posted as answers by new users. Instead, let's **encourage** them to **flag** the answers so moderators can intervene and turn them into comments so we do not discourage new users from sharing knowledge here.

Comment: I strongly support this line of reasoning. If a new user makes a mistake, **guide them, do not punish them**. Turning an answer into a comment can be confusing, but it makes a far warmer welcome than downvotes and full deletion.